# How to make my webpage not look so flat?

Tags: website-design, gui-design, color-scheme, font

I am creating a website and my skills are in the back-end and unfortunately, I always have to end up doing the front-end as well. The coding is not the problem, it is the design and color choices. All my websites on the client-side end up looking very flat and boring and makes them look unprofessional (which they are from the front-end lol) so I am in search for tips on how to make the website "pop", not look so flat and mix colors correctly. I have attached a screenshot of the current login page for a website and could use some advice on how to make this not look so flat and boring.[image: login page example]

I know it is not centered, that is just because I did not take screenshot of the entire screen. More specifically, I would like the "logo" in the top-left look more like a logo instead of just text on the screen. Also, need some help on how to select fonts. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Hi nd510, your question is more suited for the **Graphic Design** community. Kindly post this here https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/ and you will get your answer

Comment: @ShreyasTripathy Is there a way to transfer the question over or should I just create a new one on that site ?

Comment: Just post this question on the other site. Once done, you could close/remove this question

Comment: or a mod could migrate it for you

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is more suited for Graphic Design SE.

Comment: "I am creating a website and my skills are in the back-end..." I think you've found your problem. There are tons of visual designers who do small freelance projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I first started out in web design, I created a big folder of all the websites that I liked the look of, and then I .... borrowed heavily you might say. I looked at the colour combinations they used, their use of fonts for headings and paragraph text, I scrutinised their drop shadows, bevels (they were a thing back then) and borders. Is there something specific about the website that you could focus on for a background image? e.g. if it's a website about food, choose some delicious looking images and put the login form on top of that. Here's a pinterest board with some good imagery: https://pinterest.com/xiusheji/app-sign-in-login/

Nowadays you can start off with one of the many libraries or frameworks that has a complete style guide set up. Examples here: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/bootstrap-alternatives/ For specific colour schemes, check out what others have put together on sites like Kuler: https://color.adobe.com/explore/?filter=newest

For the company logo, you can utilise services such as Google Fonts. https://fonts.google.com/?category=Display,Handwriting Type in the company name and look at non-paragraph text fonts (so check options for Display and Handwriting to start). You can then scroll through pages of options. Fonts like Lobster and Pacifico show that linking the letters together makes it look less like text.

Also pop into the folks at Graphic Design if you haven't already: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/ They might have their own suggestions.

Best of luck! The more you keep designing, the better you'll get at it.

Comment: Thank you, I will definitely check out the sources you mentioned. And I actually didn't know there was a graphic design site so I'll check it out!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you may find some awesome flat colors at [flatuicolors.com](http://flatuicolors.com/). You can create awesome shades according to your choice or your customer's choice.

Second thing, a text-only layout makes the user feel bored so try to use some icons from [fontawesome](http://fontawesome.io/cheatsheet/) or stock images to increase the readability.

Third and last, always try to separate the call to action button (in your case it is Signup) by giving importance to it. I attached an image of my design for your understanding.

[image]

Comment: And thousands of typographers scream in horror.